# How to get the stack trace pointing to actual error reason

Tags: go

Let's say I have some code like this:

```
value, err := some3rdpartylib.DoSomething()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

In case `err != nil` I will get something like this:

```
panic: some error explanation here

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /tmp/blabla/main.go:6 +0x80
```

This stack trace is completely legit but sometimes these error messages may not clarify what happened and so I'd like to dig deeper into the source code of the 3rd party library to investigate what exactly causes this error to be returned. However when my code panics like this, there is no way to get the actual place that returned this error.

A little bit more clarification: as I'm coming from JVM world where exceptions are thrown I can completely trace what exactly line of code thrown the exception and thus can easily find the place and see what gone wrong. Go stack trace ends exactly where my code panics and thus not too useful in my case.

I've created a playground [here](http://play.golang.org/p/5ydALOMSJi) and ideally I'd like to be able to trace the error to the place it was actually returned from, not panic. (e.g. to line 17, `return "", errors.New("some error explanation here")`)

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shortly: this is not possible.
Since [errors are values](https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values), they are not treated in any special way. Due to this, when function (normally) returns, stack is no more available (ie. another function call may overwrite memory used by returning-error function' stack).

There is a tool called *trace* which was introduced with go1.5, but for now, there is no comprehensive tutorial available neither any of those I found says that this kind of feature will be included.

Comment: Trace is competently unrelated to this problem, not sure why you mention it.

Comment: I can imagine that _trace_-like tool can record entering to and returning from any function with current context (function arguments or return values and line number when returning).

Comment: I expected it to be this way but hoped there's at least something I could wrap problematic code with (something like the trace you mentioned) to get more detailed stack trace.

Comment: I tried to use trace for this without much success. So this is why I ended up writing my own small debug utility (see my answer).

Answer (score 23):

I think that there is an easier way to achieve this. You can try [wrapping errors](https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/errors) using the golang "default" third party library error package:

You need to define the interface to be implemented by your `error` :

```
type stackTracer interface {
    StackTrace() errors.StackTrace
}
```

Then use it when wrapping/processing an error :

```
err, ok := errors.(stackTracer) // ok is false if errors doesn't implement stackTracer

stack := err.StackTrace()
fmt.Println(stack) // here you'll have your stack trace
```

Following comment by mrpandey, there are other library that allows a certain degree of error handling :

- [eris](https://github.com/rotisserie/eris) "is an error handling library with readable stack traces and flexible formatting support"
- [go-errors/errors](https://github.com/go-errors/errors) "adds stacktrace support to errors in go."
- [palantir/stacktrace](https://github.com/palantir/stacktrace) "Look at Palantir, such a Java shop. I can't believe they want stack traces in their Go code."

Comment: This is explained in the `github.com/pkg/errors` package documentation here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors?utm_source=godoc#hdr-Retrieving_the_stack_trace_of_an_error_or_wrapper

Comment: The Go standard library's error package is https://pkg.go.dev/errors
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors is a third party library

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I gotta say, the fact that stack traces are only available through third-party libraries (that are now archived) is really disappointing. This problem is especially painful with large applications or with third-party packages that don't use `pkg/errors`. Additionally, if you're developing your own third-party package, including `pkg/errors` as a dependency seems like a must. I'm baffled that Go errors don't provide stack traces in 2022.

Comment: Besides, `pkg/errors` is officially unmaintained, archived, frozen.

Comment: There are other 3rd party libraries like `eris`, `go-errors/errors`, `palantir/stacktrace`.

Answer (score 6):

As others have pointed out tracing errors in go isn't trivial. There are projects like [juju/errgo](https://github.com/juju/errgo), that allow you to wrap errors and then trace these errors back. For that to work tough, you must use them consistently throughout your project and that won't help you with errors in 3rd party libraries or with errors that get handled and never get returned.

Because this is such a common issue and I really got annoyed with this, I wrote a small [debug utility](https://github.com/gellweiler/errgotrace) that will add debug code to go files that logs every returned error (value that implements `error`) and the function in which it was returned to STDOUT (if you need more advanced logging just hack the logger in the project, it's really simple).

**Installation**

```
go get github.com/gellweiler/errgotrace
```

**Usage**

To debug all files in the current directory:

```
$ find . -name '*.go' -print0 | xargs -0 errgotrace -w
```

To remove the added debug code from the go files:

```
$ find . -name '*.go' -print0 | xargs -0 errgotrace -w -r
```

Then just simply compile & run your code or your test cases.

**Sample Output**

```
[...]
2017/12/13 00:54:39 [ERRGOTRACE] parser.*Parser.objectKey: EOF token found
2017/12/13 00:54:39 [ERRGOTRACE] parser.*Parser.objectItem: EOF token found
2017/12/13 00:54:39 [ERRGOTRACE] parser.*Parser.objectKey: EOF token found
2017/12/13 00:54:39 [ERRGOTRACE] parser.*Parser.objectItem: EOF token found
2017/12/13 00:54:39 [ERRGOTRACE] parser.*Parser.objectKey: At 3:4: nested object expected: LBRACE got: ASSIGN
2017/12/13 00:54:39 [ERRGOTRACE] parser.*Parser.objectItem: At 3:4: nested object expected: LBRACE got: ASSIGN
2017/12/13 00:54:39 [ERRGOTRACE] parser.*Parser.objectList: At 3:4: nested object expected: LBRACE got: ASSIGN
2017/12/13 00:54:39 [ERRGOTRACE] parser.*Parser.Parse: At 2:31: literal not terminated
2017/12/13 00:54:39 [ERRGOTRACE] parser.Parse: At 2:31: literal not terminated
2017/12/13 00:54:39 [ERRGOTRACE] hcl.parse: At 2:31: literal not terminated
2017/12/13 00:54:39 [ERRGOTRACE] hcl.ParseBytes: At 2:31: literal not terminated
2017/12/13 00:54:39 [ERRGOTRACE] formula.parse: parsing failed
[...]
```

As you can see from this output, it's really easy to tell in which function the error originally occurred. Once you know that, you can use a debugger to get more context.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at https://github.com/ztrue/tracerr

I created this package in order to have both stack trace and source fragments to be able to debug faster and log errors with much more details.

Here is a code example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "github.com/ztrue/tracerr"
)

func main() {
    if err := read(); err != nil {
        tracerr.PrintSourceColor(err)
    }
}

func read() error {
    return readNonExistent()
}

func readNonExistent() error {
    _, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/non_existent_file")
    // Add stack trace to existing error, no matter if it's nil.
    return tracerr.Wrap(err)
}
```

And here is the output:
[image: golang error stack trace]

Comment: @Alpha2k I tried to run this code on go 1.13.4 on macos and it seems fine, could you please provide more details?

Answer (score 5):

```go
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    value, err := DoSomething()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(value)
}

func DoSomething() (string, error) {
    return "", errors.New("some error explanation here")
}
```

The problem is the standard package `errors` does not attach the stack trace at the point it occurs. You can use [github.com/pkg/errors](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors#hdr-Retrieving_the_stack_trace_of_an_error_or_wrapper) to do that:

```go
package main

import (
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    value, err := DoSomething()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%+v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(value)
}

func DoSomething() (string, error) {
    return "", errors.New("some error explanation here")
}
```

```
$ go run stacktrace.go
some error explanation here
main.DoSomething
    /Users/quanta/go/src/github.com/quantonganh/errors/stacktrace.go:18
main.main
    /Users/quanta/go/src/github.com/quantonganh/errors/stacktrace.go:10
runtime.main
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.15.2/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:204
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.15.2/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374
```

More details: https://dave.cheney.net/2016/06/12/stack-traces-and-the-errors-package

Comment: Note: use the `%+v` variant to print the error with the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: https://github.com/efimovalex/stackerr

Is this the thing you are looking for?

```
package main

import "github.com/efimovalex/stackerr"
import "fmt"

func f1() *stackerr.Err {
    err := stackerr.Error("message")
    return err.Stack()
}

func f2() *stackerr.Err {
    err := f1()
    return err.Stack()
}

type t1 struct{}

func (t *t1) f3() *stackerr.Err {
    err := f2()
    return err.Stack()
}

func main() {
    ts := t1{}
    err := ts.f3()

    err.Log()
}
```

Result:

```
2017/08/31 12:13:47 Error Stacktrace:
-> github.com/efimovalex/stackerr/example/main.go:25 (main.main)
-> github.com/efimovalex/stackerr/example/main.go:19 (main.(*t1).f3)
-> github.com/efimovalex/stackerr/example/main.go:12 (main.f2)
-> github.com/efimovalex/stackerr/example/main.go:7 (main.f1)
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you wrote down the lines numbers :)

Answer (score 1):

As I know, stackrerror is the simplest stack display package. You can use all the native log library records or output the call stack yourself. For example:

```golang
    package main

    import "github.com/lingdor/stackerror"

    func act1()error {
    return stackerror.New("here Error")
    }

    func main(){
    err:=act1()
    fmt.println(err.Error()) //panic(err) and log.Info(err) are ok
    }
```

output :

```
*stackError.stackError : here Error
at main.act1( /Users/user/go/testMain/src/main/main.go:17 )
at main.main( /Users/user/go/testMain/src/main/main.go:22 )
at runtime.main( /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.4/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:203 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in Recover function to handle panic and print the stack trace.

From https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

> Recover is a built-in function that regains control of a panicking
>   goroutine. Recover is only useful inside deferred functions. During
>   normal execution, a call to recover will return nil and have no other
>   effect. If the current goroutine is panicking, a call to recover will
>   capture the value given to panic and resume normal execution.

I have modified your example to use recover and [eris](https://github.com/rotisserie/eris). Eris provides a better way to handle, trace, and log errors in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/rotisserie/eris"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    value, err := DoSomething()
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r!= nil {
            fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%+v", r))
        }
    }()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(value)
}

func DoSomething() (string, error) {
    return "", eris.New("some error explanation here")
}
```

The output is:

```
some error explanation here
    main.DoSomething: /tmp/sandbox147128055/prog.go: 23
    main.main: /tmp/sandbox147128055/prog.go: 9
    runtime.main: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go: 203
    runtime.goexit: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64p32.s: 523
```

See it in action here https://play.golang.org/p/jgkaR42ub5q

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe no one mentioned the amazing [cockroachdb/errors](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/cockroachdb/errors): a well-maintained library with the following features:

- Error chaining `.Wrap()`
- Error encoding: JSON, Sentry
- Mark error as "handled"
- Add a secondary error
- **Stack traces**
- Add contextual information to an error
- Add user-facing information: human-friendly text
- Generate PII-free details (without personally identifiable information)

Sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/cockroachdb/errors"
)

// Leaf error: standard error
var LeafError = errors.New("Database error")

func main() {
    // Call a function that fails
    _, err := startTransaction()

    if err != nil {
        // Return a wrapped error with more information
        var returnedError = errors.WithHint(
            // Wrap the returned error with our standard error
            errors.CombineErrors(LeafError, err),
            // User facing error
            `Sorry, there is an issue. Please try again later.`,
        )

        // okay we'll actually print it. Use "%+v" to see stack traces.
        fmt.Printf("Error: %+v\n", returnedError)
    }
}

// Sample function that fails
func startTransaction() (any, error) {
    return nil, errors.New("Failed to start a transaction")
}
```

Sample output:

```
Error: Database error
(1) Sorry, there is an issue. Please try again later.
Wraps: (2) secondary error attachment
  | Failed to start a transaction
  | (1) attached stack trace
  |   -- stack trace:
  |   | main.startTransaction
  |   |         /home/kolypto/c0de/medthings/cerebellum/cerebellum/play.go:32
  |   | main.main
  |   |         /home/kolypto/c0de/medthings/cerebellum/cerebellum/play.go:14
  |   | runtime.main
  |   |         /usr/lib/go-1.20/src/runtime/proc.go:250
  |   | runtime.goexit
  |   |         /usr/lib/go-1.20/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1598
  | Wraps: (2) Failed to start a transaction
  | Error types: (1) *withstack.withStack (2) *errutil.leafError
Wraps: (3) attached stack trace
  -- stack trace:
  | main.init
  |     /home/kolypto/c0de/medthings/cerebellum/cerebellum/play.go:10
  | runtime.doInit
  |     /usr/lib/go-1.20/src/runtime/proc.go:6506
  | runtime.main
  |     /usr/lib/go-1.20/src/runtime/proc.go:233
  | runtime.goexit
  |     /usr/lib/go-1.20/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1598
Wraps: (4) Database error
```

Answer (score 0):

I made [a spiritual successor of `github.com/pkg/errors`](https://gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors) named `gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors` some time ago [which addresses a long list of issues](https://gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors#why-a-new-go-errors-package) `github.com/pkg/errors` has and can be used as maintained and drop-in replacement for `github.com/pkg/errors`.

`github.com/pkg/errors` is uses modern error handling patterns in Go, and learns from many issues Go community discovered through time. For example:

- It does not use discouraged `runtime.FuncForPC` function to make sense of the stack trace internally, [but `CallersFrames`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#Callers) which supports inlined functions.
- When stack trace recorded, only minimal necessary information is recorded, all other information is resolved when needed (e.g., formatting) so that error creation is fast.
- All information stored in errors (record traces and optional structured details) is extractable from errors through interfaces not using custom types so that your codebase does not have to depend on `github.com/pkg/errors` if some dependency you are using is using it.
- The package is also interoperable with other popular errors packages so it can be used in codebases with mixed errors packages. It can also be used to unify them, e.g., format all errors in the same way. It knows how to extracts stack traces if already recorded from some of them.
- Supports sentinel (base) errors and in general supports a pattern where you use just constant errors and not ad-hoc created errors.

And of course it records stack traces and formats them.

For the example OP made, you can just replace `errors` import with `gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors` and [get](https://go.dev/play/p/N9DzD3UOWxf):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors"
)

func main() {
    value, err := DoSomething()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(value)
}

func DoSomething() (string, error) {
    return "", errors.New("some error explanation here")
}
```

Output:

```
some error explanation here
main.DoSomething
    /tmp/sandbox2002200753/prog.go:20
main.main
    /tmp/sandbox2002200753/prog.go:11
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go:267
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650
```

Sadly, default panic handler calls only `Error()` on errors so there is no stack trace. But you can use `fmt.Sprintf` and `os.Exit` yourself.

It tries to stay lean while providing utility functions for many common use cases. The [example from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76442643/252025) could be done with `gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors` like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors"
)

// Leaf error: standard error
var LeafError = errors.Base("database error")

func main() {
    // Call a function that fails
    _, err := startTransaction()

    if err != nil {
        // Return a wrapped error with more information
        // Combine the returned error with our standard error
        var returnedError = errors.Prefix(err, LeafError)
        // User facing error
        errors.Details(returnedError)["hint"] = `Sorry, there is an issue. Please try again later.`

        // okay we'll actually print it. Use "%+#v" to see stack traces and details.
        fmt.Printf("error: %+#v\n", returnedError)
    }
}

// Sample function that fails
func startTransaction() (any, error) {
    return nil, errors.New("failed to start a transaction")
}
```

Output:

```
error: database error: failed to start a transaction
hint="Sorry, there is an issue. Please try again later."
main.startTransaction
    /tmp/sandbox201940367/prog.go:30
main.main
    /tmp/sandbox201940367/prog.go:14
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go:267
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650
```