# Logging stack trace of any go routines

Tags: go

I have an application in which the main go routine spawns few more go routines. Is it possible to log the stack trace for any go routine that crashes? Using "defer debug.Stack()" and "recover()" in the main prints the stack trace of main goroutine as expected. Is there any way to print stack trace of the go routines spawned if they panic ?

Comment: If the goroutines panic the application should crash, which will show the stack traces. If you are recovering, then you have to handle it yourself.

Comment: "Is there any way to print stack trace of the go routines spawned if they panic ?" No.

Answer (score 3):

If a goroutine `panic`s, its stack trace will be shown.

If a goroutine is calling `debug.Stack`, its (the calling goroutine's) stack trace will be provided.

Run this example to demonstrate both:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime/debug"
    "time"
)

func foo() {
    stack := debug.Stack()
    fmt.Println("foo's stack:", string(stack))

    panic("oh noes")
}

func worker() {
    foo()
}

func main() {
    go foo()
    time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

You'll see something like:

```
foo's stack: goroutine 6 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x9f
main.foo()
    /tmp/gogo.go:10 +0x26
created by main.main
    /tmp/gogo.go:21 +0x35

panic: oh noes

goroutine 6 [running]:
main.foo()
    /tmp/gogo.go:13 +0xe6
created by main.main
    /tmp/gogo.go:21 +0x35
exit status 2
```

The first stack trace is what `foo` obtains with `debug.Stack`. The second is a result of the unrecovered `panic` crashing the process.

You can call `debug.Stack` in a `recover`. See this answer for example: [How to get the stacktrace of a panic (and store as a variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103182/how-to-get-the-stacktrace-of-a-panic-and-store-as-a-variable)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I get what you are saying, but what I am asking is,  I don't want to call debug.Stack() in every go routine.  Can't we have a cleaner way of having one function in main, that prints stack trace for any goroutine ?

Comment: @GunaKK: no, that's not possible. Each goroutine needs its own `recover`. You can abstract this away in a function