# stack trace and golang errors.Unwrap()

Tags: go, error-handling

I would like to build a stack trace that includes a low level db error with a second error which is human readable.

Is the new `errors.Unwrap()` function in golang 1.13 built for this purpose?  Not sure I understand how to use it.  Looking for an example on how to do this.

```
// model/book.go
package model

type Book struct {
    Id     uint32  `json:"id"     db:"id"`
    Title  string  `json:"title"  db:"title"`
    Author string  `json:"author" db:"author"`
    Price  float32 `json:"price"  db:"price"`
}

func (b *Book) Tablename() string {
    return "books"
}


// main.go
package main

func main() {
    bk := model.Book{
        Title:  "oliver twist",
        Author: "charles dickens",
        Price:  10.99,
    }

    err:= Create(&bk)
    if err !=nil {
        // how to use Unwrap?
    }

}
func Create(book *model.Book) error {
    insertSQL := "INSERT INTO ...."
    // code to insert
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    book.Id = uint32(lastID)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: You might find these answers useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034241/how-to-get-the-stack-trace-pointing-to-actual-error-reason-in-golang

Answer (score 23):

`errors.Unwrap` is for peeling off layers of an error that has been wrapped.

```golang
// error 1 wrapped by 2 wrapped by 3
err1 := errors.New("error 1")
err2 := fmt.Errorf("error 2: %w", err1)
err3 := fmt.Errorf("error 3: %w", err2)

fmt.Println(err1) // "error 1"
fmt.Println(err2) // "error 2: error 1"
fmt.Println(err3) // "error 3: error 2: error 1"

// unwrap peels a layer off
fmt.Println(errors.Unwrap(err3)) // "error 2: error 1"
fmt.Println(errors.Unwrap(errors.Unwrap(err3))) // "error 1"
```

You can recursively unwrap to get to the inner most error:

```golang
currentErr := err3
for errors.Unwrap(currentErr) != nil {
  currentErr = errors.Unwrap(currentErr)
}

fmt.Println(currentErr) // "error 1"
```

For an error that contains both low-level and human-readable error, you can implement a custom error.

```golang
type Error struct {
  LowLevel error
  HumanReadable string
}

func (e Error) Error() string {
  return e.HumanReadable
}

func (e Error) Unwrap() error {
  return e.LowLevel
}

// helper
func NewError(inner error, outer string) *Error {
  return &Error{
    LowLevel: inner, 
    HumanReadable: outer,
  }
}
```

In your called function:

```golang
func Create(book *model.Book) error {
  ...

  if err != nil {
     return NewError(err, "failed to create book")
  }

  ...
}
```

In your caller:

```golang
func main() {
  ...
  err := Create(&bk)
  if err != nil {
    log.Print(errors.Unwrap(err)) // internally log low-level error
    fmt.Print(err) // present human-readable error to user
  }
  ...
}
```