# Is it possible to get the source code line which return value returned?

Tags: go

When building web apps using gin/echo/mux or else, I have some handler or func with many possibility of returning error. Because of the complexity of current application, My idea is to create some post-middleware or handler and get which source code returned value come from and logging them, it is possible?

```golang
func main (){
    // is it possible to get which line returned value, i.e line 11 of main.go?
    e := Validate(10)
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: %v", e)
    ]
}

func Validate(i int) error {
    if i >= 10 {
        return fmt.Errorf("want less ten, got %v", i) // i.e line 11
    } else if i < 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("negative number: %v", i)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the stack trace pointing to actual error reason in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034241/how-to-get-the-stack-trace-pointing-to-actual-error-reason-in-golang)

Comment: You can use middleware like this. func newLoggingHandler(dst io.Writer) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return handlers.LoggingHandler(dst, h)
  }
}

Comment: Somehow, if possible there is a way without modification all handler (currently working with hundreds of handler + thousands of return errors). The current possible way is wrap all the error before return and trace from wrap. I see some answer mention this also https://github.com/ztrue/tracerr and github.com/pkg/errors

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is backwards. Don't try to figure this out from the caller--instead have the function itself include a stack trace in the error. [`github.com/pkg/errors`](https://github.com/pkg/errors) can help here.

As an example:

```golang
import "github.com/pkg/errors"

func main (){
    e := Validate(10)
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: %v", e)
    ]
}

func Validate(i int) error {
    if i >= 10 {
        return errors.Errorf("want less ten, got %v", i) // i.e line 11
    }
    if i < 0 {
        return errors.Errorf("negative number: %v", i)
    }
    return nil
}
```