# How to implement stack tracing?

Tags: go

I am trying to implement [stack error tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49005129/2138752). I am having difficulty tracing the error. The following code catches the db error. But it doesn’t trace the error:

```
// err represents *db.Error
if err != nil {
  return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "error msg")
}

// Now, in the error middleware:
func traceError(err error) {
    _, ok := err.(stackTracer)
    if ok {
        fmt.Print("tracer implemented")
    } else {
        fmt.Print("tracer not implemented")
    }
}
switch e := errors.Cause(err).(type) {
  case *db.Error:
    fmt.Print("caught db error")
    traceError(err)
  defaut:
    fmt.Print("unknown error")
    traceError(err)
}
```

Outputs:

```
caught db error
tracer not implemented
```

When I create new error the trace is implemented:

```
// err represents *db.Error
if err != nil {
  newError := errors.New(err.Error())
  return nil, errors.Wrap(newError, "error msg")
}
```

Outputs:

```
unknown error
tracer implemented
```

My desired output is:

```
caught db error
tracer implemented
```

---

**Edit:** After re-looking I found my code is working fine. I might have messed something somewhere in my code.

Comment: Well, I think I can go with that approach as well. You could post your answer with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just noticed that the question is talking about the package `github.com/pkg/errors`. Except for some syntax error in the question, it works as expected:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/fs"
    "os"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

func fn() error {
    _, err := os.Open("non-existing")
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "fn")
    }

    return nil
}

type stackTracer interface {
    StackTrace() errors.StackTrace
}

func traceError(err error) {
    _, ok := err.(stackTracer)
    if ok {
        fmt.Println("tracer implemented")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("tracer not implemented")
    }
}

func main() {
    err := fn()

    switch e := errors.Cause(err); e.(type) {
    case *fs.PathError:
        fmt.Println("caught fs error")
        traceError(err)
    default:
        fmt.Println("unknown error")
        traceError(err)
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
caught fs error
tracer implemented
```

Comment: Well. No demo needed. It worked.

Comment: if `db.Error` has the field `Code`, in the `if errors.As(cause, &dbError) {` block, get the `Code` with `dbError.Code` (`errors.As` assigns the error to `dbError`).

Comment: My pleasure! ^_^

Comment: I have replied in the chat room.

Comment: Can I connect to you somewhere in Slack?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Hi, I have ping you in Slack.